# Get value of a variable using its name in a string

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I want to get the value of a variable from its name.

To clarify, an XML document delivers the variable name as a string; I want to get the value.

Something like this:

```
string bublegumA = "strawberry";
string bubblegumB = "banana";   

//get which variable from the XML

string fromXML = "bubblegumB";

string output = getValue(fromXML);

//it should return "banana"
```

Comment: *"Using c# .net 2.0 I want to get the value of a variable from it's name."* - No you don't, you want a real solution to this problem, you just can't imagine it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, this is an application of reflection:

This should work, if it's a field:

```
var value = targetObject.GetType().GetField(fromXml).GetValue(targetObject, null);
```

So if your class is:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string BubblegumA = "Strawberry";
}
```

then in your main class:

```
public static void Main()
{
    MyClass targetObject = new MyClass();

    var value = targetObject.GetType().GetField("BubblegumA").GetValue(targetObject, null);

    //value should = Strawberry
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against advising a beginner to use reflection when a lookup table will do.

Comment: I agree, if this was a problem I was trying to solve, it's not the way I'd do it - but it is a valid answer to the problem - just not best practice.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS: Sometimes the right answer is not on which directly addresses the request, as is the case here.

Comment: I am far from a beginner. I am looking for how to do this, not how to use a dictionary. Reflection would be nice to use, if it does what I need.

Comment: The Reflection example, is nice, and is something I have been trying to use. Still, it seems to be "cranky" at me when I try it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Variable names only exist at design time. Once it's compiled (without debugging symbols) the variable name is lost.

But you can do this:

```
var myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myValues["bublegumA"] = "strawberry";
myValues["bublegumB"] = "banana";

string output = myValues["bublegumB"]; // "banana"
```

You could also use an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) if you don't like the dictionary syntax for setting properties, though you still have cast it to a dictionary to get an value by name:

```
dynamic myValues = new ExpandoObject();
myValues.bublegumA = "strawberry";
myValues.bublegumB = "banana";

string output1 = myValues.bublegumB; // "banana"
string output2 = (string)((IDictionary<string, object>)myValues)["bublegumB"]; // "banana"
```

Comment: I know you CAN do that using Reflection.

Comment: @WayneScroggins With variables, you can't. Reflection allows you to inspect the structure of types, including properties and fields (like *RussC*'s answer) but the names of variables defined within a method do not exist at run-time.

Comment: @WayneScroggins Also note that reflection is much slower than using a collection. If you're just using this as way to store name-value pairs, it's really not a good solution.

Comment: @WayneScroggins FWIW, I included an example using `ExpandoObject` which offers a different syntax, but essentially uses a dictionary to store data internally.